# Why tableview didn't show the correct image?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have two Viewcontroller A and B. A will download all the photo in collectionview then I can click on single cell to go to Viewcontroller B which is the tableview to show only this single image that passed from A.

But its working fine when first lunch the app but once I add new photo in the collectionview then I clicked this new photo to go to Viewcontroller B but B didn't show the correct photo showing some other photo. I print out the photo data `postImg` in viewcronller A and B the data is the same but B is not showing the correct photo. Why? When I rebuild the program it's working the issues seems only happened when I add new photo.

Here is code to load the pic from server

```
func loadPosts(){

        let query = PFQuery(className: "posts")
        query.whereKey("username", equalTo:PFUser.current()!.username!) 
        query.skip = self.picArray.count // skip the already loaded images

        query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in

            if error == nil {

             if let objects  = objects{ 
                for object in objects{       
                    self.collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({
                        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.uuidArray.count, section: 0)
                        self.uuidArray.append(object.value(forKey: "uuid") as! String)
                        self.picArray.append(object.value(forKey: "pic") as! PFFile)
                        self.collectionView?.insertItems(at: [indexPath])
                    }, completion: nil)

                }
              }
            } else{
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
     }
```

Then `var postImgData = [UIImage]()` is the array used to save all the photos that downloaded from above function and this viable is defined at beginning of CLASS Viewcontroll A.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return picArray.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    //define cell

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! pictureCell


        picArray[indexPath.row].getDataInBackground { (data, error) in

            if error == nil {
                cell.picImg.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                self.postImgData.append(UIImage(data: data!)!)


            } else {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Then i click the cell to go to viewcontroller B . postImg is defined at beginning of Viewcontroller B as global viable to get the image date that you click on Viewcontroller A cell.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    postImg = postImgData[indexPath.row]
    let post = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "postVC") as! postVC
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(post, animated: true)

}
```

Then in Viewcotnroller B to show the photo

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! postCell

    cell.picImg.image = postImg

    return cell
}
```

Comment: PFFile.getDataInBackground() is asynchronous. Is it OK?

Comment: Are you reloading that table row? UITableVIew does not refresh when cell is changed, let a lone, data change. You need to call `reloadData` or better `reloadRow` (and pass row number, which is 0) on your table view after new image is set.

Comment: i tried reload() still not working

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
picArray[indexPath.row].getDataInBackground { (data, error) in
    if error == nil {
        cell.picImg.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        self.postImgData.append(UIImage(data: data!)!) <== WHY do you append array?
    } else {
        print(error!.localizedDescription)
    }
```

you should probably init array beforehand and set data like self.postImgData[indexPath.row] = UIImage(data: data!)!
That how we ensure correct order of images

2

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let post = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "postVC") as! postVC
    // Why dont use post.postImg = postImgData[indexPath.row]?
    // Do not use Global vars, because you can change it from anywhere without noticing
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(post, animated: true)    
}
```

So I suggest moving *postImg* var to controller B

Comment: Hi teresa, i tried self.postImgData[indexPath.row] = UIImage(data: data!)! but it gives index out of range error. Because i have 20 photos but the indexpath is like first allocate 0 --11 then you scroll down it allocate from 11 -- 19

Comment: Also my issues is happened only the photo exceeds certain number like 16 something before 16 no issue and after 16 starting to see the issue.. so wired..